# Experimental measurement on the ring-strain

Tags: organic-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy

for my thesis i calculated the ring-strain of a molecule by MP2 on the computer. I was wondering if there is an easy possibility to get the experimental value of the ring strain. I guess I have to combust the compound and somehow calculate it from the combustion-enthalpy. My Problem is, that there is no access to the open form of the molecule to compare it. Is there still a way to calculate it?
I thought of the Hess-law maybe there is a way with some standard values? 
It is an organic molecule only containing C, H and O.

Comment: I am looking for an experimental setup such as calorimetrie oder TGA ore something to determine the ring strain of my specific molecule. The links are not helping, because my molecule is not a cyclo alkane.
You're answer seemes quite rude regarding that it is not helpful or targeting the problem at all.

Comment: You need a measure of ring strain, ie comparison of combusion energy wrt non-strained compound. Wikipedia is helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_strain

Comment: I edited my question. There is no "open form" of my molecule, well there ist but it is no accesable because I open the ring and polymerize the molecule via ring-opening metathesis polymerization.

Comment: In any case to determine something like ring strain you need an unstrained reference molecule to compare to. Then you can use Hess's law for instance, if data is available.

Comment: There has to be another way. There is a lot of experimental data in publications, but no one is explaining how it is done. There is no open form of the molecule. In Metathesis, you break the doublebond and attach it to another broken doublebond.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olefin_metathesis
Therefore, the open form with double bonds has at leaast two more methylene groups.

Comment: If I understand correctly the problem is that the initial strained molecule is a monomer and the unstrained molecule is a polymer? If so off the top of my head two ideas to start with: 1) "trap" the open form of the monomer by reacting it with something that will quench polymerization; 2) perform the combustion on the polymer but normalize by the degree of polymerization to determine individual monomeric contributions.

Comment: Basicly that is the problem yes. I can not trap the open form. The ring opens via metathesis, so the doublebonds breaks and forms 2 new doublebond with 2 new carbon atoms. So even if i stop the reaction, it wont be the correct form as it contains more carbon. If I trap it without adding carbon, then I loose my doublebond which also has an impact on the energie of the molecule. 
It is hard to determine the exact chain length, because I' measuring it via GPC which is an relativ measurement no absolut. As the molecule is new, there is no standard for it to get an exakt amount of repeating units.

Comment: In the absence of more info I'd say you want to study the transition state during the reaction, and there are definitely ample ways of doing this at the ab initio QM level.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with that. Did you look at the Metathesis mechanism, take cylcopentene for example. The open form would be penten. That already has 2H more. Now there is no way to just open cyclopentene. When you do ring-opening metathesis, you end up with Hept-1,6-en. When you do the ring-closing of the Hept-1,6-en you end up with cylcopentene and ethene. So it would be the correct linear form for this reaction type but include 2 CH2 more than the original one.
How do you want to trap the transition state as a stable product which you can combust in a calorimeter afterwards?

Comment: I mean *ab initio* (eg DFT or other) modeling of different structures. You start with monomer and transform into transition state, finally product. There are people well versed in how to do this. See eg references associated with https://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/99638/factsheet/en , or search for "ab initio modeling olefin metathesis"

Comment: For an older ref: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/om00002a024

Comment: I don't mean *at all* experimental determination, unless you have some spectroscopic way of catching signatures of the intermediate. This may be possible in the gas phase, not sure if in solution. And when I say "in gas phase" I mean, if that is at all possible.

Comment: But now I'm really out of my league: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja078149z?journalCode=jacsat  etc ...

Comment: Perhaps also this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/46972552/om020581w20160703-24993-bp1p.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1545146847&Signature=EyC1D%2FNMf6RUg5BSg4tU7U5jDZU%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DMolecular_Modeling_of_Ruthenium_Alkylide.pdf